# Tangent Line that Intersects An Intercept

Tags: calculus

In a recent homework for one of my economics classes, I was put in a scenario where I needed to find a line tangent to $x^2y=16000$ that intersects the point $(0, 30)$. How do I go about making that happen? My teacher keeps telling us to "use algebra", so I'm not sure she knows what she's talking about, and problems of this variety have thus far been untouched in class.

Comment: Do you know how to find the slope of that tangent by implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(p,q)$ be the (unknown) point of tangency. Then $q=\frac{16000}{p^2}$.

The derivative of $\frac{16000}{x^2}$ is $-\frac{32000}{x^3}$. So our tangent line has slope $-\frac{32000}{p^3}$.

The tangent line goes through $(0,30)$. So it has slope $\frac{q-30}{p}$. This is $\frac{16000}{p^3}-\frac{30}{p}$. It follows that
$$\frac{16000}{p^3}-\frac{30}{p}=-\frac{32000}{p^3}.$$
Solve for $p$.

**Remark:** The calculations will be more pleasant if we use *implicit differentiation* to calculate $\frac{dy}{dx}$, using the relationship $x^2y=16000$. We chose to do it using explicit differentiation because that is likely to be more familiar.

If we do it the implicit differentiation way, we get $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=0$. We cannot have $x=0$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2y}{x}$. At $(p,q)$ this is $-\frac{2q}{p}$.

As before, the slope of the tangent line is $\frac{q-30}{p}$.  Set this equal to $-\frac{2q}{p}$. We get $q=10$, and therefore $p^2=1600$.